# MFC app doesn't work on 2003/XP anymore after upgrading to VS 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, mfc, windows-xp

So I have a SDI MFC application which worked flawlessly on Windows XP & Server 2003.

I had to update the project to VS 2013, and since then the application cannot properly load the ribbon anymore.

I had to set the toolkit to Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp) for the app to even load on XP, which it does, but then it can't load the ribbon.

I've narrowed it down to the call to LoadFromResource() which fails (without much details). Since 2003 is no longer a supported platform for the remote debugger, I can't investigate much.

I also can't go back to 2010, since the project utilizes features from the v120 CRT, and it would require a lot of tweaking.

Here is the code. As you can see it's able to create the ribbon, but it can't load it from the resource.

```
bool ribbonCreatedSuccesfully = ribbonBar_->Create((CWnd*) this);

if (ribbonCreatedSuccesfully)
{
    ribbonBar_->RemoveAllCategories();

    if (!ribbonBar_->LoadFromResource(IDR_RIBBON1))
    {
    ^ fails here
```

The application is statically linked and works correctly on all later platforms (2008, Win7, ...).

I know it's a long shot to get this figured out, but I'm hoping that somebody may have run into a similar issue.

Comment: What exactly does *"fails here"* mean? The code enters the error branch? The application crashes? The code enters the success branch, but the control won't show up? Something else altogether? What you can try, however, is dump the error code (from [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx)), if the call fails. This is not guaranteed to produce a reliable value, since MFC is involved. It may still give you useful hints, if MFC doesn't modify the error code.

Comment: With "fails" I meant that LoadFromResource() returns FALSE. The result is that I essentially have an empty ribbon. I'll try the GetLastError(), I didn't think that it would help me at the time. But if that's all I have then I'll give it shot. Thanks.